# Angular $resource POST

Tags: angularjs

I got this following example working with GET.. But 'doSave' is not working for POST.
Am I overlooking some?

---

```
    $scope.obj1 = $resource('http://localhost:port/srv/:id',
            {port: '\:8080', id:'2', callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},
            {get:{method:'JSONP'}, save:{'POST'});


    $scope.doSearch = function () {
    $scope.Result = $scope.obj1.get({id:$scope.term});
    }

    $scope.doSave = function () {
    $scope.Result.save();
    }
```

Comment: Not sure about your problem, but it may be worth a look at following discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/_LRK9h9j-Yg/ZmOkv-uhVcAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the query/get methods, the rest are called prefixed with $ ($resource.$save(), $resource.$remove(), etc)

So in doSave you need

```
$scope.Result.$save();
```

More details in the [official docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

Comment: I am trying to use $resource with different URL for each GET and POST.. Do you have any idea?

Comment: in my case it's making a `POST` with url-encoded values rather than a json object. but my `Results` are from `.query` . is that the problem?